# Best practice of managing database connections in a web app

Tags: java, mongodb, design-patterns, database

I am developing a MongoDB app with Java but I think this question related to datastore connections for web apps in general.

I like to structure all web apps with four top-level packages which are called (which I think will be self explanatory):

- Controller
- Model
- Dao
- Util

Ideally I would like to have a class in the Dao package that handles all the connections details.

So far I have created a class that looks like this:

```
public class Dao {

public static Mongo mongo;
public static DB database;

public static DB getDB() throws UnknownHostException, MongoException{
    mongo = new Mongo("localhost");
    database = mongo.getDB("mydb");
    return database;
    }

public static void closeMongo(){
    mongo.close();
    } 
}
```

I use it in my code with something like this

```
public static void someMethod(String someData){
    try {
        DB db = Dao.getDB();
        DBCollection rColl = db.getCollection("mycollection");      
        // perform some database operations
        Dao.closeMongo();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } catch (MongoException e) { e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine, but I'd be curious to know what people think is the "best" way to handle this issue, if there is such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you can write a java class to establish the connection with the database.

The arguments to the method should be the `database name`, `password`, `host port` and other necessary credentials.

You can always call the parametrized constructor everywhere where there is a need to establish database connectivity. This can be a model.

Comment: So you're suggesting getting a new connection every time an operation is to be performed. I was wondering if there's a way to reuse connections (which is why I've made the methods/parameters of Dao static ... although maybe I am just wondering about something that has no purpose/doesn't exist.

Comment: @Ankur: yes exaactly get a new connection this will add more security to the connections and also help you resue the method where ever the new connections are to b established with different machines or server. just change the parameters and u get the connection. This is basicaly what i feel is better way to handle connections in MVC

Comment: getting a new connection every time will result in poor performance.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb when connecting to relational database server is to have a pool. For example if you connect to an oracle database using a pool gives you some performance benefits both in terms of connection setup time and sql parsing time (if you are using bind variables). Other relational database may vary but my opinion is that a pool is a good pattern even for some other reason (eg. you may want to limit the maximum number of connections with your db user). You are using MongoDB so the first thing to check is how MongoDB handles connections, how expnsive is creating a connection,etc. I suggest to use/build a class that can implements a pool logic because it gives you the flexibility you may need in the future. Looking at your code it seems that you api

```
DB db=Dao.getDB();
```

should be paired with:

```
Dao.closeDB(DB db);
```

So you have a chance to really close the connection or to reuse it without affecting the Dao code. with these two methods can switch the way you manage connections without recoding the Dao objects

Answer (score 1):

I got a 'nice' solution from this article. http://www.lennartkoopmann.net/post/722935345

*Edit* Since that link is dead, here's one from [waybackmachine.org](http://waybackmachine.org)

http://web.archive.org/web/20120810083748/http://www.lennartkoopmann.net/post/722935345

**Main Idea**

What I found interesting was the use of a static synchronised method that returns an instance of the static class and its variables. Most professional devs probably find this obvious. I found this to be a useful pattern for managing the db connections.

**Pooling**

Mongo does automatic connection pooling so the key is to use just one connection to the datastore and let it handle its own pooling.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better if you call a method inside DAO to get data from database as well. If you do it in this way, say your database got changed. Then you have to edit many classes if you get data directly calling db queries. So if you separate db calling methods inside the DAO class itself and call that method to get data it is better.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you've written. But yes I agree you don't want to have to change many classes if the db parameters (username, pwd etc) change.

Comment: Where did you put "public static void someMethod(String someData)" ? I think it is good if you put all the db calling methods inside DAO class. Not only the methods for connection establishment